# Combine thousands of logger instances

Tags: apache-2.4, rsyslog

We have Apache 2.4 setup with over 1000 vhosts, and multiple instances of logger in each :

> CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t apache-access -p local6.notice -n
> x.x.x.x" access_log

Restarting httpd takes 90+ seconds because it's opening thousands of connections to the rsyslog server.

Any advices on how to make it more efficient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the logs go to the same server, I believe you can avoid this by having a single `CustomLog` entry in the
main part of the server configuration, not in each `VirtualHost`.  You can
use a single `LogFormat` using `%v` to have the virtual hostname in the
message if you need it for further processing at the rsyslog receiver.
See the discussion under [File Descriptor Limits](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/fd-limits.html).